# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Tags: highcharts

I have a stockChart which has 2 data series. It displays well in the first place.

[image]

But when we unselect a data serie (e.g. `FFSite`), it raises an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')`. Does anyone know what may be the reason?

[image]

PS: A live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7vfsgc?file=index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a regression bug in Highstock. I have reported it with a minimal example here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16351

The issue doesn't occur in the versions below 9.2, so for now you can use some lower versions.